# How to refresh the map in react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I used [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) in my location tracking application. And now i want to clear ( refresh ) the map with all the markers and poly-lines without refreshing react component , when user stop the location Tracking ( using a button ).Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

At some point if you wish to change what is visible on your component in react, there's no other way than rerendering your component.

I do not know `react-native-maps`, but I think this problem can be solved using general react knowledge.

Markers and polygons in `react-native-maps` are added as children of the `MapView`, so depending on how you are storing your markers/lines, you should be able to simply rely on react's state or props changes to update your `MapView`.

For example, if your markers are stored in your component's state, you could do something like this:

```
class MyLocationTracker extends React.Component {
  state = { markers: [{ latlng: { latitude: 1, longitude: 1 } }] }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text onPress={() => this.setState({ markers: [] })}>Reset markers</Text>
        <MapView>
          {this.state.markers.map((marker) => <Marker coordinate={marker.latlng} />)}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When the `state` changes, react will call the `render()` function again and update the markers. Note that this will also serenader the `<MapView />` component.
If you wish to avoid rerendering the `<MapView />` component, you can move the logic to a new component that will handle the markers only, like so:

```
class MyLocationTracker extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text onPress={this.markers.reset}>Reset markers</Text>
        <MapView>
          <MyMarkers ref={(comp) => { this.markers = comp }} />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class MyMarkers extends React.Component {
  state = { markers: [{ latlng: { latitude: 1, longitude: 1 } }] }

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({ markers: [] })
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.markers.map((marker) => <Marker coordinate={marker.latlng} />)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Again, changes in the state would trigger a rerender of your component. But now, since only `<MyMarkers />`'s state changes, it will rerender itself but not anything else.

I hope that helps :)